# drow part of image in browser using css

Tags: html, css, image, background, slice

Prompt, whether it is possible to use pieces of the image img, but so that these images have been compressed (normal operation with img)

For example I have 'images/myimg.png' image, but I want to display only part of the coordinates 0.100 and size 250x75, and the browser that this image was the size of 100x50

```css
.myimg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  content: url ( 'images / myimg.png');
  / * Pseudo-attributes - what I would like to find * /
  content_pos_x: 0px;
  content_pos_y: 100px;
  content_width: 250px;
  content_height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<img class = 'myimg' />
```

---

I understand that I can use another way:

```css
background: url ( 'images / myimg.png') 0px 100px;
```

but in this case, image's scaling are not available :(

Comment: Why are you using the `img`-tag without an `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a `img`-tag without an `src`? You dont need to use an `img`-tag if you want to have a image.

You could try this:

CSS:

```
#foo {
    background-image: url("http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100429000907/jamescameronsavatar/images/e/e5/Google_Chrome_Icon.png");
    background-position: -50px -30px;   // This is the position
    background-size: 223px 99px;        // This is the scaling
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hddq1bp7/1/)

Comment: "Why are you using a img-tag without an src?"

for vertical align of text after image

--

thanks for your example (background-size)

Comment: @Zhihar If this helped you, feel free to upvote or / and accept the answer. This will help other users.

Answer (score 1):

For rectangular clipping, I find it simple to use a container div that can clip:

```
<div class='clipper'>
  <img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

The CSS would use overflow hidden, position relative and position absolute as follows:

```
.clipper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clipper img {
  width: 640px;          /* Target width of image */
  height: 480px;         /* Target height of image */
  left: -30px;           /* Offset to first visible pixel in target size */
  top: -50px;            /* Offset to first visible pixel in target size */
  position: absolute;
}
```

So Basically, you can do it, but your content rectangle has to be pre-calculated into target size units and applied as the clipper WxH and the img offset.